# Space on right of website when viewed on iPhone

Tags: iphone, css, safari

Here is a screen shot to show exactly what I mean:

[image]

The green vertical line on the right image shows the space that appears when viewed on iPhone Safari. I don't think this has anything to do with Safari since I've seen other websites without that space. Is this something wrong with the css? If so, what's the problem?

The actual site is shown in the address bar of the image if viewing the site live helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the width of this div element to this...

```
#tweet-bar-content {

    width: 970px;
}
```

Comment: you're about 5 pixels over on that div. Adjusting this should remove the line on the side.